# What does the FIDE president do?

Tags: fide

What is the role of the president of the International Chess Federation? What does he or she do, and what is he or she supposed to do?

I have looked at sources such as [Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE)

Comment: Well, the former one tried convincing people that we need to teach chess or else aliens would destroy the Earth.

Comment: I know that's why I just commented. Nothing much happened, it's just well known he believes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FIDE President's role is defined in one of the FIDE Handbooks on the FIDE website. The relevant part is [Chapter 09 - The President and Deputy President](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=46&view=article) in the [FIDE Statutes](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=1&view=category).

There it says -

> 9.1.  The President represents FIDE officially and can solely sign for FIDE.  All contracts signed by the President shall be subject to prior
>   approval or subsequent ratification by the Presidential Board. Any
>   contract that commits FIDE to an obligation or exposes FIDE to a
>   potential liability of more than €100,000 must be submitted for
>   ratification by the Executive Board or General Assembly.
>   9.2.  The President presides over the meetings of the General Assembly, the Executive Board and the Presidential Board.
>   9.3.  The President presents an annual report to the General Assembly.
>   9.4.  The President’s decisions may be appealed to the General Assembly, Executive Board or Presidential Board.
>   9.5.  If the President is unable to act or if he duly authorises, then he can be represented by the Deputy President who shall exercise the
>   powers of the President. The Deputy President can thus represent FIDE
>   officially and can solely sign for FIDE.
>   9.6.  In certain cases the FIDE President can also delegate specific tasks to other persons; this includes authorising in writing other
>   FIDE officials to sign contracts on his behalf.

Details of the [General Assembly](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=41&view=article), the [Executive Board](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=42&view=article) and the [Presidential Board](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=44&view=article) are given in the FIDE Statutes.